# Watch infinite loop on using background

Tags: sass, compilation, infinite-loop

```
.checkbox-group {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    &:checked {
      + .pseudo-checkbox {
          background: red;
          background: url("../../images/tick.png") no-repeat;
      }
    }
  }
  span.pseudo-checkbox {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid $input-border;
    //background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

When using sibling selector and background image, sass watch compiler goes into infinite loop (using laravel mix). Her i have included my sass. If I comment the  background, the compilation works good.

Comment: please ignore background: red.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/432 seems a bug here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/npm-run-watch-in-infinite-loop-laravel-54 .

Comment: @AvneshShakya Thank you this worked

Comment: Awesome (y). I am happy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the image to the original folder before compiling not the after compiling folder, i usually have the same problem but solve it by naming the before compiling img and the compiler  will create new one it will name it images,